# Using POST forms as navigation in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am working with an already existing application that uses things like:

```html
<form action="some.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="billing">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Billing">
</form>
```

The downside of this implementation is that if you click back you have to refresh the page in order for it to display. In some cases their are multiple navigation buttons you have to click on to get to a part of the application and if you click back, and refresh, there are variables that aren't set because the user never went back to the first step in the chain so then the page gives you an error.

I've seen other applications do this but it has been a really long time. Should I just change all of the PHP scripts so that they use $_GET and just use dirty/ugly URLs to route views?

What is the "current" method of doing this?

Comment: Why are you mixing things? `GET` is for getting the values, `POST` is for adding new values. Both are different methods. Looking at the question, it seems that you won't mind using `DELETE` in place of `POST`

Comment: _'What is the "current" method of doing this?'_ - of implementing basic navigation on a website? Normal links inside the HTML and GET as the request method, of course. _"and just use dirty/ugly URLs to route views?"_ - what would be "ugly" about `/actions/billing/` or similar?

Comment: what you call "ugly" is more secure and genuine, try links like /?